# Can't load IA 64-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

My machine is a 64 bit if i run tomcat Apache Tomcat/8.0.15 direct from the command line it loads fine on my localhost. My environment variable is 64 bit. I am trying to run a spring project from intellij. I have setup tomcat and the sdk both at 64 bit.

I get this error though
Can't load IA 64-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

My machine is 64 bit
tomcat is 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

If you go here : http://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi and download the tomcat-native-1.2.4-win32-bin.zip binary. You'll see a directory like tomcat-tomcat-native-1.2.4-win32-bin.zip\bin\x64\  If you take that binary and put it in your bin folder it should fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load IA64 libraries/binaries on x86_64, those are completely different platforms. Itanium has nothing to do with x86.

Comment: I dont understand my machine is 64 bit no mentioned of x86

Comment: First of all, there is no 64 bit version of Tomcat. You have a x86_64 CPU and you try to load a binary for a IA-64 CPU. This is not possible.

Comment: my pc is 64 bit. Where is the 32 bit coming from?. My pc is 64 bit

Comment: No one is talking about 32 bit. You are obviously not reading my answers carefully enough.

Comment: x86 is CPU architecture like many others like ARM, Itanium, etc.